# Loop through observable<Object[ ]> in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a firebase database... So it's all JSON.
I retrieve the data using AngularFire2 database...I'm reading [this](http://javasampleapproach.com/firebase/ionic-3-firebase-example-crud-operations-with-firebase-realtime-database) tutorial...

The part of the code for this question is :

```
noteList: Observable<Note[]>

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private noteListService: NoteListService) {
    this.noteList = this.noteListService.getNoteList()
      .snapshotChanges()
      .map(
      changes => {
        return changes.map(c => ({
          key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val()
        }))
      });
```

From here I want to do 2 things :

- 1st : declare an array variable outside of the contructor, just like `noteList` Ex : `myVar: Note[] = new Array();`
- 2nd : Iterable though the result of the `getNoteList()` and push them into that variable for futher use... I hope to have `myVar` holding multiple objects of `Note` ...=> those are JSON from Firebase therefore JavaScript objects...

How do I do that ?

What I've go so far is using the following :

`this.noteList .forEach(value => console.log(value));` This will log each element of noteList  as `Array [Object]` ....

When I do `this.noteList .forEach(value => this.myVar.push(value));` it says :

> Argument of type 'Note[]' is assignable to parameter of type 'Note'. Property 'id' is missing in type 'Note[]'

The comple class code is :

```
export class HomePage {

  noteList: Observable<Note[]>
  myVar : Note[] = new Array();

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private noteListService: NoteListService) {
    this.noteList = this.noteListService.getNoteList()
      .snapshotChanges()
      .map(
      changes => {
        return changes.map(c => ({
          key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val()
        }))
      });
  }

  this.noteList .forEach(value => this.myVar.push(value));

  //Then below, I want to use it in a Jquery 

  $(function() {
     // Also, I don't know how to access neither noteList nor myVar here. Any help here will be appreciated also
  }
}
```

Could you guyz help be do this please...

Comment: The question is likely XY problem. You're trying to integrate modern approach (this is Angular+Ionic, isn't it?) with old-school 'jQuery programming'. This should never be done. jQuery is absolute no-no in Angular app for numerous reasons. Regarding *Then below* and *I don't know how to access neither noteList nor myVar here*, this is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call . You need to embrace observables, not create bridges to jQuery which you're likely more familiar with. You can access a value in observable `.subscribe`

Comment: @estus ohh tell me about that... Programming has gone a LONG way I know I need to update my skills... I'll think about your advice about jquery... But for the `.subscribe` part, any heads up from you would be appreciated.... How would I iterate though `.subscribe` result to allow me to construct `myVar` with `Array.push` method ?

Comment: You don't need to iterate it. It's `.subscribe(notes => { this.myVar = notes })`

Comment: @estus Thank you Mate... It worked... You can add it as an answer if if you want vote my OP up ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The proper way to do this with RxJS is to subscribe an observable and do all necessary actions with result inside `subscribe` callback. If the observable isn't reused, it isn't necessary to save it to `noteList`, but a subscription possibly needs to be saved in order to unsubscribe it and avoid memory leaks:

```
  noteListSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private noteListService: NoteListService) {
    this.noteListSubscription = this.noteListService.getNoteList()
      .snapshotChanges()
      .map(
      changes => {
        return changes.map(c => ({
          key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val()
        }))
      })
      .subscribe(notes => { this.myVar = notes });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    noteListSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

`Subscription` type should be imported from `rxjs` module.

Comment: When/how is `noteListSubscription` instantiated ?

Comment: There was a typo, fixed it.

Comment: Yeah... It works fine now... Thank you mate. Do not forget to  indicate the `import` for `Subscription type`... Thank you mate you've helped me a lot. Please vote my question up it you want or helpme to improve it ;-)